# python for parallel numerical computaion

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

i am working on a python application which involves large set of numerical data. the data is segregated into groups in first step and then the group can be independently computed.

i tried using threading.Thread() but soon realised its of no use due to gil.

```
class vThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self,item):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.item = item

    def run(self):
        do_stuff()

vThreads = [] 

for item in items:
    vThreads.append(vThread(item))    
    for x in vThreads:
        x.start()

    for x in vThreads:
        x.join()
```

i also tried multiprocessing.Process() but all it does is creates new instances of my parent process and not subprocess (implemantation similar to threads just replace Thread by Process)

is there any other way i can implement parallel processing in my situation?
number of independent computations are in thousands.

Comment: There is also [MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/numpyscipy-with-intel-mkl).

Comment: typo? what does vThread(item) return? edit - oh I see, it is different from vThreads. My bad.

Comment: jst edited it. it was wrongly typed. its jst a identifier and nothing else

Comment: I don't understand what "i also tried multiprocessing.Process() but all it does is creates new instances of my parent process and not subprocess" means. It's true that on Windows your subprocesses are newly-created instances rather than forks, but they're still subprocesses. More importantly, what's actually _wrong_ when you use multiprocessing? Not what do you think causes the symptoms, what _are_ the symptoms?

Comment: As a side note, trying to run thousands of threads or processes simultaneously (on a system with 4-16 cores, which is what I assume you have) is a terrible idea; you'll spend more time context-switching than running. You only want one thread or process per core running at a time. (The simplest way to do that is with a `multiprocessing.Pool` or `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`, but you can do it manually if you really want to.)

Comment: Also, if you're doing thousands of computations on a large set of data, are you using NumPy? If not, why not? It'll probably give you a 6x or better speedup out of the box—and many NumPy operations actually release the GIL, meaning sometimes threading lets you parallelize things.

Comment: i m using pandas library which already uses numpy.
i tried using pool on smaller sample data. result is similar to Process(). say if i have 5 processes in pool, 5 windows of my application start, this is what i meant with multiple instances

Comment: What kinds of computation are you doing? Could you give an example? You said you tried with pandas/numpy, but did you set it up in a way that takes advantage of vectorized computation?

Comment: For example, if A and B are numpy arrays, the following is really fast:
import numpy as np; 
A = np.random.random(99000); 
B = np.random.random(99000); 
res1 = A + B; 
res2 = A / B; 
res3 = np.sqrt(A); 
res4 = np.log(B); 
res5 = (res1 + res2)/(res3 * res4);

Comment: i have large set of records, generally > 200000 in excel format, i need to group them and segregate.. then i need to do some simple computations on groups like aggregate, average etc and then save... i am using pandas and computation i m doing sequently on the groups... what i need is a way to do that on groups paralley since they are independent

Comment: Would [mrjob](https://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/) be of any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Python3 you can use the [concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) to run several independent tasks in parallel.

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for item in items:
        executor.submit(do_stuff, item)
```

On Python2 you can use the [multiprocessing.Pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) class to achieve same result.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

pool = Pool()

for item in items:
    pool.apply_async(do_stuff, (item, ))
```